# how to create site map xml in php

Tags: php, xml

Hi i want to create sitemap.xml form database data in php.

My current code in below i am getting data form database.

```
$show_data = "query to database";
$rows = mysqli_query($conn, $show_data);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)){
    echo "<url>\n";
    echo "<loc>https://example.com/page/".$row['id']."</loc>\n";
    echo "<lastmod>".$date_show."</lastmod>\n";
    echo "<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>\n";
    echo "<priority>0.80</priority>\n";
    echo "</url>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_result` implements `Traversable` (PHP >= 5.4), so you can use it directly in a `foreach`. Combine that with XMLWriter and you are done.

```
$targetFile = 'php://stdout';
$xmlns = 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9';
$date = date('Y-m-d');

$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openUri($targetFile);
$writer->setIndent(2);
$writer->startDocument();
$writer->startElementNS(NULL, 'urlset', $xmlns);

foreach ($queryResult as $row) {
  $writer->startElement('url');
  $writer->writeElement('loc', 'https://example.com/page/'.urlencode($row['id']));
  $writer->writeElement('lastmod', $date);
  $writer->writeElement('priority', '0.80');
  $writer->endElement();
}

$writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```